# Floating a button to the right while keeping the height and vertical center of the text

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I have a `button` inside of a `dt` element.

[image: starting image]

Everything looks fine, however I want to float the button to the right.

[image: float right]

When I add the float on the button, now the `dt` is shorter causing it to look poor.

[image]

Adding `overflow:auto` fixes this, but now the text on the left is not vertically centered. `vertical-align:center` does not fix this nor does it help by hacking it with `display:table-cell;` Is there another way of accomplishing this that I am overlooking?

`<dt style="overflow:auto">Title <button style="float:right">save</button></dt>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally how I would do this.

My CSS:

```css
dt {
    display: block;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#bfbfbf 0%, #828282 100%);
    background:         linear-gradient(#bfbfbf 0%, #828282 100%);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 400px;
}

dt:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    float: none;
}

dt p {
    display: inline-block;
}

dt button {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    float: right;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<dt>
    <p>My Title</p>
    <button>Save</button>
</dt>
```

Just remember that your text block "My Title" needs to be an `inline-block` and not a `block`

I hope that helps or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. This gets the job done, however, I had to change `dt p` to `display:inline`. A height of 0 proves that they are vertically centered which is good. http://jsfiddle.net/9hkLt/

Answer (score -1):

There are better approaches than simply floating the elements around.  I would suggest either wrapping them with div elements, or creating a table, assuming of course that you plan on repeating the title-button structure.  A sample may be something like:

```
<div style="width:50%;">Title</div>

<div style="width:50%;">
    <button style="float:right">Button</button>
</div>
```

EDIT---

Try the quick-and-dirty table approach:

```
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr><td>Title</td>
    <td><button style="float:right">save</button></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Also, what's with the dt element?

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to clear your floated element instead of using `overflow:auto;`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/UGWuc/

---

#### EDIT

Try this now: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/6HXek/5/

The button had some padding that the title did not have. This makes them have matching vertical padding.

Comment: I put that in my code and that doesn't fix the problem that my title is not vertically aligned with the button on the dt. http://jsfiddle.net/6HXek/

Comment: Does the example link look correct to you?  If so, you might have some other CSS styles doing that.  Try modifying the example so it behaves like what you are seeing.

Comment: No, in both your and my jsfiddle, the title on the left is not vertically aligned with the button. There is more space on the top of the title than on the bottom.

Comment: Updated my answer, check the new link.

Comment: Putting equal padding on top and bottom of the elements only works if the elements are the same height. They are not.